# Getting the nth route parameter in a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a route defined in routes.php similar to:

```
Route::get('something/{firstId}/{secondId}/{thirdId}/{nthId}', 'SomeController@read')->name('read');
```

In my controller, I have it setup like this, which works perfectly:

```
public function read($firstId, $secondId, $thirdId, $nthId, Request $request){
   ...
}
```

I don't need `$firstId`, `$secondId`, etc for the particular method. I just need the `$nthId`. Is it possible to setup my controller so I can just grab the nth parameter and simplify my code? For example:

```
public function read($nthId, Request $request){
   ...
}
```

Comment: You have necessity to add the id in the route, If you use array input field it would be easier.

Comment: It would be a bad design to omit parameters from your method. What if another developer worked on it. How would they know this? Ask yourself that when you're developing code.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That's a really good point, but generally when working on a controller, I assume that future devs will also look at the route definition. That's what I'd hope, anyways.

It just seemed strange to me to have a controller that didn't need a couple of parameters, but now I'm thinking about refactoring routes. Essentially, does my route really need to be that deep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set argument list using **variadic** a preceeding `...` there is an interesting caption on php.net [arguments page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) and here is it:

[image]

Therefore in your case you would have:

```
public function read(Request $request, ...$ids){
   $id2 = $ids[1]; //here is the second path parameter in /id1/id2/id3/..n
   ...
}
```

One thing is that variadic parameters have to be last in the declaration.

> Ps: I might not be totally correct about injecting other parameters but at least with the example above, it worked correctly.

Comment: Not bad, didn't think of using "..."! The only thing to keep in mind is to keep the things injected by the service provider first. i.e. Move $request and other objects to the front like: public function read(Request $request, SomeOtherServiceProvider $service, ...$routeParameters)

Comment: @Foo, check my updates, actually your thought is actually correct and it will work as you said